# When I add a SVG with fixed positioning my form and hover states on my button stop working

Tags: html, css, forms, svg

I have a link here to https://codepen.io/PhysicsKid/pen/gQXPPZ.

```
svg {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

This is they styling that I have on the SVG. I have a hover state for the submit button also.

```
button:hover {
  color: white; 
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  border: 3px solid white;
}
```

When I comment out the SVG the form and the hover state both work. I am not sure what is causing the problem. I think the SVG might be covering the other elements so that they can not be selected but if that is the case I do not know how to fix it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `pointer-events: none;` to the css definition for the SVG. This will keep it from blocking the mouse events from the elements placed below it (which is the root of your issue). [See the fixed example here](https://codepen.io/zeroskillz/pen/VVreVg)